# Datatables handle array data in the footer filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with footer filtering. 
Each column has 1 value which works perfect with the default way of handling the footer filtering:

```
//Add footer filtering
this.api().columns([2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]).every(function () {
    var column = this;
    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on('change', function () {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                $(this).val()
            );
            column
                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                .draw();
        });
    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
        console.log(d);
        if (d) {
            var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
            select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>')
        }
    });
});
```

Now the exception (column 6); there is one column which is filled in with 3 possibilities:

1) **empty**

2) **array with one value**

3) **array with multiple values**

[image]

Atm when selecting an option in the dropdown the filtering will not find any results i think because it searches on text and the data there is send as an array (see below). The html in de datatable itself is inserted as followed:

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">suborg test met lange titel</span>
```

I've searched far and wide but I cannot seem to find a correct approach for my solution.
The result should be that the footer filter dropdown will contain a row for each seperate tag and that it actually filters.
So the ideal outcome would be:

[image: (empty)]

(note that this is edited directly in the HTMl as ex)

In the code snippet above there is a console log which shows how the data is passed for that column:

[image]

I've figured to create a specific footer filtering for that column but i'm really stuck on how to handle the array data:

```
this.api().columns(6).every( function () {}
```

Who can provide me the golden tip i'm missing?

Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

I've been able to loop through the data and get better options in the dropdown:
[image]

This by using the following code:

```
column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
    if (d) {
        $.each(d, function (index, value) {

            var val = $('<div/>').html(value).text();
            select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>');
        });

    }
});
```

However the filtering doesn't match any results in the datatable..
Still very stuck on this.

Comment: you can loop through it if its an array, and then create a search string or however you want.

Comment: @AhmedSunny Thank for that insight which I missed. I used this approach now to fill the dropdown better (edited the Q) but I still cannot match any data in the datatable

Comment: try this, add  type: 'html'  to the columndef of tags column. and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you remove these search extra values and check

> column.search(val **? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false**).draw();

to

> column.search(val).draw();

```
you can also search each column through--

//indexcolumn--where we need the filter (column index )



  initComplete: function()
     {
    this.api().columns(indexcolumn).every(function() 
    {
        var column = this;
        $('input', this.header()).on('keyup', function() {
          if (column.search() !== this.value) {
            column
              .search(this.value)
              .draw();
          }
        });
      });

    }
```

> for more information--
>               https://jsfiddle.net/vigneshwarannevilish/gx5vh9jm/73/

Comment: Do you happen to know a way to remove duplicate values in the dropdown as well in the current setup?

Comment: Ok no worries I figured it out by crosschecking with an extra array indexof the value

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stand-alone solution, using a slightly different approach.

You can load the following text into a file and open it in a browser. It contains two filters:

- a text input filter on column 1
- a drop-down (select) filter on column 2

The filters work in combination with each other (which I assume you would want, if you have multiple column filters of different types).  The drop-down is ordered and de-duped, and is based on the tags in the table's column, when the table is first rendered.

There's a global search field, but that can be switched off if you don't need it.

An example screenshot:

[image]

The HTML page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Animals</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">
  <style>
    .boxed {
      border: 1px solid grey;
      padding: 2px;
      margin: 0 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
   <tr><th>Animal</th><th>Color</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>antelopes</td><td><span class="boxed">blue</span><span  class="boxed">green</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>elephants</td><td><span class="boxed">red</span><span  class="boxed">yellow</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>hounds</td><td><span class="boxed">blue</span><span  class="boxed">green</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>kittens</td><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>lions</td><td><span class="boxed">blue</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>ravens</td><td><span class="boxed">black</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>whales</td><td><span class="boxed">red</span><span  class="boxed">green</span></td></tr>
    <tr><td>zebras</td><td><span class="boxed">blue</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr><th>Animal</th><th>Color</th></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

  // DataTable
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  // Setup - add a text input to first footer cell
  $('#example tfoot th').slice(0, 1).each( function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
  } );

  // Setup - add a select list to second footer cell
  $('#example tfoot th').slice(1, 2).each( function () {
    var html = buildDropdown();
    $(this).html( html );
  } );

  $('#colorSelect').change(function() {
    table.draw();
  });

  // Apply the input field search
  table.columns().every( function () {
    var that = this;

    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change clear', function () {
      if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
        that.search( this.value ).draw();
      }
    } );
  } );

  function buildDropdown() {
    var selectHtml;
    var items = [];
    table.columns([1]).data().each(function (d, j) {
      $( "span.boxed" ).each(function( index ) {
        var newItem = $( this ).text();
        if (items.indexOf(newItem) === -1) {
          items.push(newItem);
        }
      });
    });
    items.sort();
    //console.log(items);

    selectHtml = '<select id="colorSelect"><option value=""></option>';
    items.forEach(function(item) { 
      selectHtml = selectHtml + '<option value="' + item + '">' + item + '</option>';
    });
    selectHtml = selectHtml + '</select>';

    return selectHtml;
  }

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
      var selectedValue = $('#colorSelect').val();
      if (data[1].includes(selectedValue)) {
        //console.log("match!");
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  );

} );


</script>

</body>
```