# DataTables Filter Dropdown - Parse list, contains not exact

Tags: datatables

So my javascript is bad, but I have a datatables need that I cannot figure out. Relevant code here:

```
$('#lesson-table').DataTable( {
                'data': cleanData,
                'paging': false,
                'order': [[ 8, 'asc' ], [ 3, 'desc' ], [ 1, 'desc' ]],
                initComplete: function () {
                // this is where we populate the filter dropdowns
                this.api().columns([0,1,2,6,7]).every( function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );

                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        } );

                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        var val = $('<div/>').html(d).text();
                    select.append( '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>' );
                    } );
                } );
            }
        } );
            // this removes duplicate dropdown values
            var usedNames = {};
            $("#lesson-table select > option").each(function () {
                if (usedNames[this.value]) {
                    $(this).remove();
                } else {
                    usedNames[this.value] = this.text;
                }
            });
```

So the change that was made in my datasource is that columns 1, the second column in the set, is now a comma separated list of items. Most of the time it is one item say: "Entertainment", but sometimes it can be "Entertainment, Sports, Healthcare" At the moment, it will show that list as an option in my dropdown, but what I need it to do is split them up and then filter by contains...not by exact.

Hope that makes sense. Can explain more if needed.

Comment: Your scenario is similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60531288/12567365). Maybe you can adapt that to your needs.

Comment: It might be but I'm not good enough with my javascript to figure out how to adapt it.